# Sort an array based on a similar array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have 2 arrays with numerical indices that have the same number of keys and similar but not identical values. $unordered has the unordered data, whereas array $ordered has the data in the proper order. I want to sort $unordered in the same order as $ordered, but keep the percentage values in square brackets from $unordered.

$unordered:

```
[0] => "Horse [1%]"
[1] => "Cat [5%]"
[2] => "Dog [94%]"
```

$ordered:

```
[0] => "Cat"
[1] => "Horse"
[2] => "Dog"
```

Thanks.

Comment: What's the relationship? I don't see any common denominator here

Comment: I think he wants `$undernored` to have the same sequence as set by the `$ordered` array.

Comment: What is the order? Alphabetical is not right. Letter count is not right. So how are you sorting it?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy: I think he wants to sort `$unordered` by the order of the values in `$ordered`.

Comment: How is `$ordered` ordered?  Is that a fixed order, or should it be sorted by name?

Comment: $ordered is sorta ordered randomly - not alphabetical or letter count - so that's why I'm wondering if there's a way to order $unordered by $ordered rather than sorting $unordered alphabetically/etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`usort` is your go-to sorting function when it comes to complicated things like your example.

Try something like this.  Basically, it parses the value from `$unordered`, then searches for it in the `$ordered` array.

```
usort($unordered, function($a, $b) use($ordered){
    $aVal = explode(' ', $a);
    $bVal = explode(' ', $b);

    return array_search($aVal[0], $ordered) - array_search($bVal[0], $ordered);
});
```

DEMO: https://eval.in/184201

Comment: Was just in the process of writing something similar. This example worked for me. +1.

Comment: For the occasional value, there may be multiple spaces before the [%] eg. A large animal [56%]. Is there a way to modify the explode statements so they don't just look at the first set of characters? Sorry, ran into this problem as I tried to implement it.

Comment: @user3600400: A (cheesy) solution would be to do `explode(' [', $a)` instead.  That seems to work.  Otherwise, you'd have to use a regex.

Comment: I updated both `$aVal` and `$bVal` to `$aVal = explode(' [', $a);` and `$bVal = explode(' [', $b);` which seemed to work. Didn't work with changing just $aVal. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. Yeah, I should've mentioned to change both a and b :-)

Answer (score 2):

Although Rocket Hazmats looks nicer and is better, but you can probably understand this

```
 $array = array();
 $array[] = "Horse [5%]"
 $array[] ="Cat [1%]";
 $array[] ="Dog [99%]";
 $ordered = array();
 $ordered[] = "Cat";
 $ordered[] = "Horse";
 $ordered[] = "Dog";
 $var = "";

 $a = array_fill(0, count($ordered), '');
 for($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++){
    preg_match("/[a-zA-z]+/", $array[$i], $var);
    for($j = 0; $j < count($ordered); $j++){
      if($var[0] == $ordered[$j]) $a[$j] = $array[$i];
    }
 }

 return $a;
```